# How do I use Msg.exe to send messages on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I've got a question about using `msg` in batch files, so I can send messages to specific users on my organisation's domain.

I decided to use `net send` and realised it would only work on Windows XP. We use Windows 7 and I found out only `msg` would work.

The code so far:

```
@echo off
title MESSENGER
cls
echo ___ _  __           _ ___ _        
echo  ) / ) )_)    )\ ) / ) ) / ` )_)
echo ( (_/ /      (  ( (_/ ( (_. ( (
echo       ___  __   __   _        _   ___ __                                      
echo  )\/) )_  (_ ` (_ ` /_) )\ ) / _  )_  )_)                                     
echo (  ( (__ .__) .__) / / (  ( (__/ (__ / \                                                                                                                                                   
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL                                                                                                              
cls
:START
title Top Notch MessEnger!
cls
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo TOP NOTCH MESSENGER!
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo The usual children. Send them a message today!
echo.
set /p u=Enter username here: 
set /p m=Enter message here: 
msg  %u% %m%
pause
cls
title MESSAGE SENT
cls
echo MESSAGE SENT
pause
goto :START
```

Now, this does work but ONLY can be sent to the user signed in on that very machine, which is frustrating. I'm currently using [this site](https://www.lifewire.com/msg-command-2618093) to help.

How do I send a message to a specific user on a Windows 7 domain called School?

Comment: A school really ought to know how to spell **messenger** :/

Comment: @DavidPostill I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I send a message to a specific user on a Windows 7 domain?

> **Sending and receiving Net Send messages in Windows 8/7/Vista**
>
> In order to send or receive Net Send messages on Windows versions that
>   don't support Net Send command (Windows 7, Vista, ME, 95, 98) you can
>   use third party software products. We suggest using [Winsent
>   Messenger](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/messenger/), [Winsent Innocenti](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/innocenti/) and [Sent](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/sent/) utility.
>
> Winsent Messenger is a messenger for LAN, compatible with net send.
>   Winsent Innocenti is a pared-down version of the Winsent Messenger,
>   only allowing message receiving. Sent is a console utility intended
>   for sending messages from command line.
>
> The following are step by step instructions on how to add NET SEND
>   support to Windows 7:
>
> 1. Download and install Winsent Messenger or Winsent Innocenti on all
>      computers that should be used for message receiving (Go to the
>      download page).
> 2. Download and install Sent utility and Winsent Messenger on all
>      computers that should be used for message sending (Go to the download
>      page)
> 3. Change Windows system settings according to the requirements on all
>      the computer where you installed Winsent Messenger, Winsent Innocenti
>      and Sent.
>
> Now you can send and receive NET SEND messages on Windows 7. If you
>   need to send the message from command line then type the sent command
>   in a command prompt, otherwise use Winsent Messenger.

Source [Sending and receiving Net Send messages in Windows 8/7/Vista](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/netsend/#q3)

Comment: That's great @DavidPostill however is there a way of sending messsages WITHOUT 3rd party applications?

Thanks

Comment: @yg.swagness Not that I know of.

Comment: thanks very much. I will upvote the answer and tick as it is the best option I have